# Asus rampage II - NB Overheated. Should I worry about it?

Tags: asus, overheating, temperature

I have an old, but cool MB Asus RAMPAGE Extreame II. Suddenly the system shut it down, then at boot up I got warning. Sensors got those numbers:

```
poweruser@home:~$ sensors
    atk0110-acpi-0
    Adapter: ACPI interface
    3.3V Voltage:           +3.33 V  (min =  +2.97 V, max =  +3.63 V)
    5V Voltage:             +4.95 V  (min =  +4.50 V, max =  +5.50 V)
    12V Voltage:           +12.31 V  (min = +10.20 V, max = +13.80 V)
    CPU Voltage:            +1.04 V  (min =  +0.80 V, max =  +1.80 V)
    CPU PLL Voltage:        +1.81 V  (min =  +1.50 V, max =  +2.00 V)
    QPI/DRAM Core Voltage:  +1.19 V  (min =  +0.80 V, max =  +1.50 V)
    IOH Voltage:            +1.14 V  (min =  +0.90 V, max =  +1.35 V)
    IOH PCIE Voltage:       +1.51 V  (min =  +1.20 V, max =  +1.80 V)
    ICH Voltage:            +1.11 V  (min =  +0.90 V, max =  +1.35 V)
    ICH PCIE Voltage:       +1.51 V  (min =  +1.20 V, max =  +1.80 V)
    DRAM Bus Voltage:       +1.48 V  (min =  +1.40 V, max =  +1.90 V)
    CPU FAN Speed:          692 RPM  (min =  600 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)
    CHA_FAN1 FAN Speed:       0 RPM  (min =  600 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)
    CHA_FAN2 FAN Speed:       0 RPM  (min =  600 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)
    CHA_FAN3 FAN Speed:       0 RPM  (min =  600 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)
    PWR_FAN FAN Speed:        0 RPM  (min =  600 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)
    OPT_FAN1 FAN Speed:    1213 RPM  (min =  600 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)
    OPT_FAN2 FAN Speed:       0 RPM  (min =  600 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)
    OPT_FAN3 FAN Speed:       0 RPM  (min =  600 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)
    CPU Temperature:        +44.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +65.0°C)
    MB Temperature:         +40.0°C  (high = +45.0°C, crit = +55.0°C)
    SB Temperature:         +57.0°C  (high = +65.0°C, crit = +65.0°C)
    NB Temperature:         +99.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +80.0°C)
    OPT_FAN1 Temperature:    +0.0°C  (high = +45.0°C, crit = +45.0°C)
    OPT_FAN2 Temperature:    +0.0°C  (high = +45.0°C, crit = +45.0°C)
    OPT_FAN3 Temperature:    +0.0°C  (high = +45.0°C, crit = +45.0°C)
```

I removed the heatsink, cleaned and added new thermal paste, but no changes. Any ideas?
[Photo](https://www.asus.com/media/global/products/W7i5W4Pw4fH22Mih/DlYJoK4pMeQpsW1v_500.jpg)

Comment: Your north bridge is on fire at 99C. Maybe you can stick a fan on top of it or watercool it.

Comment: Since you say this is an old system, I would also double check the voltages of the power supply to make sure they are within spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is off-topic since it is a mobo matter and nothing to do with Ubuntu.

However, your whole box is running very hot and especially your NB CPU chipset.

I'd be looking at general cooling issues such as good airflow, cleaning filters and how hot the environment around the computer is.

The CPU fan is running rather slow which indicates it may be a cheap, inefficient fan and probably not PWM.

If you plan on using this computer as a "daily driver", you should clean it up as noted above.  And invest in a decent CPU fan and heatsink.  A PWM, liquid cooled setup will bring those temps way down.  A chipset heatsink will certainly help a lot.  Or even adding more/better case fans.

Also, if you are overclocking, turn that off.  Your cooling setup clearly isn't up to supporting that.

Comment: Sorry for off topic. It is a new case with a new CPU cooler which was special purchase. Trust me it has a huge heatsink and low RPM as I wanted. I hate noise from my CPU FAN. The setup was made month ago all new components with old MB. So the problem is not a thermal paste on NB.  It just appeared like skyrocket from nowhere. Ohh, no OC here.

Comment: If the temp is that high when idling and if you do indeed have a huge heatsink, I'd try re-applying the thermal paste again and make sure that the heatsink is correctly mounted over the CPU.  Also, note that a low RPM fan is not going to draw as much heat from the heatsink as quickly as a faster PWM fan will.

Comment: I suppose NB heatsink is not sharing heat from CPU sink, they are two seperate things. NB bridge got his own passive heatsink CPU has active heatsink with FAN? Correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: Chipsets do tend to get hot, especially if they are fanless.  I'd worry about anything over around 80c.  Adding a couple of case fans will certainly help.  Your one case fan isn;t running that fast.  I know you are sensitive to noise but there are quiet high airflow fans out there.  There are chipset cooling setups out there but given the age of Northbridge you might have trouble finding one.    I was thinking more of better CPU cooling as a means to cool the whole mobo down some.  44c is slightly high for an idle CPU.